# A subset of plane that meets every line at length one

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Is there a subset of plane whose intersection with every line has length one?

It is easy to construct such a set under the continuum hypothesis. Also, no such set is Lebesgue measurable - See [Theorem 7](http://mk.eigen-space.org/ps/fsteinhaus.pdf) in M. Kolountzakis and M. Papadimitrakis, Measurable Steinhaus sets do not exist for finite sets or the integers in the plane.

This was previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091006/subset-of-plane-with-measure-1-in-all-lines).

Comment: Interesting question . . . just to clarify -- do you want your set to have outer measure one on every line, or do you also require that its intersection with each line is measurable? The closest thing I know of to this is that there is a subset of the plane meeting every line in a Cantor set. (See https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/slicesets1.pdf) But the construction there does not allow you to control the measure of your Cantor sets.

Comment: I meant that the intersection with each line is measurable and has length one. If we only require them to have outer measure one then the answer is yes (in ZFC).

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing that might be discussed in Fremlin's book *Consequences of Martin's Axiom* (if indeed it cannot be proved in ZFC). I don't have access to this book right now but did you check there?

Comment: Re: "If we only require them to have outer measure one then the answer is yes (in ZFC)" — Could you expand on this?

Comment: Let the least size of a non null set be $\kappa$, $|\mathbb{R}| = \lambda$. If $\kappa = \lambda$, proceed as before. So assume $\kappa < \lambda$. Let $\{  L_i : i < \lambda \}$ list all lines. At stage $i$, assume $S \subset W_i = \bigcup_{j < i} L_j$, $S \cap L_j$ has outer measure 1 and size $\kappa$ for every $j < i$ and if 3 points in $S$ are collinear then they lie on $L_j$ for some $j < i$ - So $|S \cap L_i| \leq 2$. Choose $A \subset L_i \setminus W_i$ of outer measure 1 and size $\kappa$ such that no point in $A$ lies on a line passing through two points in $S$ and add $A$ to $S$.